# Simpler Proof for the Special Case

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, normed-spaces

> Suppose $1 \le p < \infty$ and $f_n ,f \in L^p[0,1]$. If $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, then prove that $||f_n-f||_p \to 0$ iff $||f_n||_p \to ||f||_p$.

The above problem does not come the real analysis text I am using as a reference (Real Analysis by Royden & Fitzpatrick). However, in that book is a proof of the above problem; in fact, a proof of more general case when the measure space finite or infinite. My question is, is there a reason the above problem uses a finite measure space? Is it possible that the proof of the above problem admits a "simpler" proof than the general case? (Okay: I realize that the proof of the general case is itself not very difficult).

Comment: This seems to be Scheffe's lemma, and the usual proof is just an application of Fatou's lemma, whether the measure is infinite or not. Are you looking for a proof that avoids the use of Fatou's lemma?

Comment: @YeZ Sheffe's lemma (according to the wikipedia page) is just the special case of $p=1$. For $p \in [1, \infty)$, the proof requires some other tricks, such as the convexity of $t \mapsto t^p$ and defining a new sequence in terms of $f_n$ and $f$. However, I am wondering whether it is possible to reduce the general case to the $p=1$ case. Here are some thoughts: suppose $||f_n||_p \to ||f||_p$ and $f_n, f \in L^p(E)$. Then $|f_n-f|^p \in L^p(E)$ and $|f_n - f|^p \to 0$. If we could argue that $||~ |f_n-f|^p||_1 \to 0$, maybe this would help...Something about this seems circular, though...